# Test the "loading" state in an Ember acceptance test

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

In my acceptance test, I want to confirm that the "loading indicator" is properly shown and hidden during an async action. Let's say I have an action that looks like this:

```
myAction() {
    this.set('isLoading', true);
    someAsyncMethod().then(answer => {
        this.set('isLoading', false);
    });
}
```

And a template that looks like this:

```
<button class="my-button" {{action "myAction"}}>
  {{#if isLoading}}
    <i class="loader"></i>
  {{/if}}
  Click me !
</button>
```

And finally, the test:

```
test('My super action', function(assert) {
    visit('/my-route');
    andThen(() => {
        click('.my-button');
        // Here, since the click() helper is async, the action isn't 
        // called, so the loader isn't shown yet.
    });
    andThen(() => {
      // Here, the load is finished, so the loader is removed
    });
});
```

My question is : Where can I do the assertion that the loader is shown ?

Answer (score 0):

```
test('My super action', function(assert) {
  visit('/my-route');
  andThen(() => {
      click('.my-button');
      // Here, since the click() helper is async, the action isn't 
      // called, so the loader isn't shown yet.
      Ember.run.next(function () {
        //here is fine, as we are in the next run loop the promise returned in the action has started loading
      });
  });
  andThen(() => {
    // Here, the load is finished, so the loader is removed
  });
});
```